# Targeting an array is returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I get this log by `console.log(data);`:

[image]

I'm trying to target data by `data[0].data` but it's not working. I get `Uncaught TypeError: data[0] is undefined`.

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` and post the data as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: Generally occurs when you try to access the array before an asynchronous operation has populated it. Check the length , it's probably zero. The console will show updates made to that object after you log it

Comment: With JSON.stringify I get [] an empty array

Comment: @HereticMonkey it does answer but it won't tell me how to fix it!

Comment: We are going to need more context, then. Because clearly what you are `console.log`-ing is not the same thing as you are actually trying to access.

Comment: I have 2 AJAX calls and I'm pushing the data into it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Most notably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call